# Apollo GraphQL query inside of react custom hook

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to list all the characters from Rick & Morty API. I wrote the following hook to use in my Component that is going to render the result. When I hardcoded values eg:  `(page: 1 , filter: { name : "Rick"})` The query runs just fine.If I try to use variables it returns an error 400 bad request (I'm assuming this means my $page / $filter values are invalid and I tried to check the values within them + their types everything seemed fine)I looked at the documentation at [Apollo | Queries - Client (React)](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/) and made sure that I was using the proper syntax to inject variables into the query. The query is from the official Rick & Morty API docs [API Docs](https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#graphql). Any guidance/direction is much appreciated.

**useCharecterList Hook**
**Params: page: Number | filter: String**

```js
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const CHARECTERS_LIST = gql`
query ($page: Number!, $filter: String!){
  characters
    (page: $page , filter: { name : $filter}) {
        info {
          next
          prev
        }
        results {
          id
          name
          image
        }
      }
  }
`;

export default function useCharecterList({page, filter}){  
    return useQuery(CHARECTERS_LIST, {
      variables: {page, filter}
    });
}
```

Component Rendering the results:

```js
import useCharecterList from '../hooks/useCharecterList'
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import InputComponent from './InputComponent';


function CharectersList() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useCharecterList({page: 1, filter: "Rick"});
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;
  const options = data.characters.results.map(({name}) =>{
      return name;
  })
  return(
    <Fragment>
      <InputComponent options={options}></InputComponent>
      {
           data.characters.results.map(({ id, name, image }) => (
            <div key={id}>
                <img src={image} alt={`${name} from the popular sitcom Rick & Morty`}/>
                <p>{name}</p>
            </div>
          ))
      }
    </Fragment>
  )


}

export default CharectersList
```

Comment: test in playground using 'query variables' option ... check network request and response **in details**

Comment: `useCharecterList(vars){  
    return useQuery(CHARECTERS_LIST, {
      variables: vars` ?

Comment: ... but previous should work, too ... bad variable (`$filter`) type - it must match BE/API specs ... as always, not tested in playground ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out... Like an Idiot I assumed the query types are just your normal JS types. After some digging I got it to work as follows.

```js
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const CHARECTERS_LIST = gql`
query CharectersList($page: Int!, $filter: FilterCharacter!){
  characters
    (page: $page, filter: $filter) {
        info {
          next
          prev
        }
        results {
          id
          name
          image
        }
      }
  }
`;

export default function useCharecterList(options){  
    return useQuery(CHARECTERS_LIST, options);
}
```

```js
import useCharecterList from '../hooks/useCharecterList'
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import InputComponent from './InputComponent';


function CharectersList() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useCharecterList({variables: {page: 1, filter: { name: "Summer" }}});
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return <p>Error :(</p>}
  const options = data.characters.results.map(({name}) =>{
      return name;
  })
  return(
    <Fragment>
      <InputComponent options={options}></InputComponent>
      {
           data.characters.results.map(({ id, name, image }) => (
            <div key={id}>
                <img src={image} alt={`${name} from the popular sitcom Rick & Morty`}/>
                <p>{name}</p>
            </div>
          ))
      }
    </Fragment>
  )


}

export default CharectersList
```

Comment: useless hook/construction ... it's enough to load/import query from separate `.graphql` file and use normal `useQuery`